# css3 animation is not working in Safari

Tags: css

CSS3 animation is not working for me in Safari (works ok in other browsers), I tried splitting out the shorthand so each property is declared separately eg:

```
 -webkit-animation-name: glow;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
```

......

But still doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
.light:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:rgba(64, 61, 51, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
    transition:all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
.light.turned-on:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    z-index:1;
    background:rgba(255, 242, 204, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
    transition:all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
.game-area.won .light:after {
    -webkit-animation-name: glow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: forwards;
    -moz-animation: glow 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: glow 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: glow 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        background: #FFF2CC;
    }
    10% {
        background: #FFF2CC;
    }
    30% {
        background: #C58FCC;
    }
    50% {
        background: #AE86B2;
    }
    70% {
        background: #B2A57D;
    }
    90% {
        background: #B2FFEB;
    }
    100% {
        background: #B2FFEB;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that in Safari 8.0.7 (10600.7.5) you cannot use `animation` on `display: inline` elements. Since `display` is `inline-block` or any other, animation works.

I hope it will help someone.